# Sliding Panel in Prototype

Tags: prototypejs, sliding

is there any Sliding Panel Available that is created in Prototype Framework??

it will be nice if it is sliding from right side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the script.aculo.us library on top of it (written by the same guys)

Link to library:
http://script.aculo.us/

Link to sliding stuff:
http://madrobby.github.com/scriptaculous/effect-move/